# Bounding the product of a sequence

Tags: asymptotics, summation, products

I am trying to find an upper bound for the following sequence:

$$(1-p_1)(1-(p_1+p_2))\cdots(1-(p_1+\cdots+p_n))$$

with $n$ groups to multiply. I have written it like this:

$$\prod_{i=1}^n \left({1 - \sum_{j=1}^i {p_j}}\right)$$

Where $p_i$ denotes a constant in the open interval $(0,1)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1$.

Here's what I've attempted to do:

$$\prod_{i=1}^n \left({1 - \sum_{j=1}^{i}{p_j}}\right) = \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1 - O(1) \right) = \prod_{i=1}^n 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n O(1) = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n O(1)$$

But I don't know how to bound $1 - \prod_{i=1}^n O(1)$.

Comment: there is no $i$ in your expression. I suppose the sum goes from $j=1$ to $i$

Comment: I will edit my post to clarify.

Comment: Can $\sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k >1$?

Comment: @Alex: No, I should have mentioned that. Thank you. More precisely, $\sum_{k=1}^n p_k = 1$. I'll also edit this into my question.

Comment: if this is so, your last term is $0$ and so the producut equals $0$

Comment: :( I'm sorry, I should have proof read my question more before posting. @Yimin was correct the first time, and the inner sum should go from $j = 1$ to $i$. Sorry guys, thanks for your patience.